# Configuring Mingw64 for 64bit

Tags: gcc, configure, mingw-w64

I’m trying to configure Mingw64(mingw-w64-v3.1.0.tar.bz2).

I ran  `./configure` and got following messages.

```
configure: Configuration Options Summary:
configure:
configure:   WinCE runtime........: no
configure:   Win32 runtime........: yes
configure:   Win64 runtime........: no
```

The configuration itself was fine. I was able to install it.

But directory name which mingw was installed is `lib32`

I think I haven’t installed Mingw64 for 64bit as configuration message said.

How can I configure it for 64bit?

I’ve tried `–build` option like `./configure –build=x86_64-w64-mingw32`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to make sure you have a cross-compiler GCC and binutils (i.e. `x86_64-w64-mingw32-[gcc,ld,dlltool,...]`) in PATH. Then, you can configure the mingw-w64-crt (do not use the toplevel configure itself) with:

```
/path/to/mingw-w64-crt/configure --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --enable-lib64 --disable-lib32
```

But the question is, why do you want to do this? There is a lot that can go wrong when building a toolchain, and there is a multitude of binaries available for virtually any platform.

Comment: Just learning.Why can’t I do config at the toplevel configure itself?

Comment: I configured without error but  got message when I did make `./mingw-w64-v3.1.0/mingw-w64-crt/intrincs/__movsb.c:1:0: sorry, unimplemented:64-bit mode not compiled in /** `

Comment: @user1345414 Are you building on Windows (MSYS or Cygwin) or Linux? In any case, send an email to `mingw-w64-public@lists.sourceforge.net` and specify all details there, like reason for doing this, and your build environment. Chances are you're doing things you shouldn't be doing because other people have done it for you. Heck, I could send you the files right now.